# request.getParameterValues in struts

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, struts

I want to convert my previous J2EE recruitment application from servlet to struts and I wanted to know if it is okay to put a request.getParameterValues("name") inside an Action class. Here is a sample code:

```
public class ConfirmEditApplicantAction extends Action{

    @Override
    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form,
            HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        String forward = "success";

            **String screenNames[] = request.getParameterValues("screenName");**

            //some codes here....


        return mapping.findForward(forward);
    }
}
```

that came from this sample form in jsp:

```
<div id="screenInformation" class="tab_content">
        <h4>Screenings:</h4>

        <form action="EditScreeningServlet" method="post">
            <input type = "hidden" name ="applicantNumber" value="${infoObj.applicantNumber}"  >
            <table>
                <c:forEach var="screen" items="${screenList}">
                    <input type = "hidden" name ="screenId" value="${screen.screenId}"  >
                   <tr>
                       <td>Screen Type: &nbsp</td>       <td><input type="text" value="${screen.screenName}" name="screenName" readonly ="true"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                       <td>Date: </td>                   <td><input type="text" value="${screen.screenDate}" name="screenDate" class="date"></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr> 
                       <td>Result: </td>               
                       <td>
                            <select name = screenResult> 
                                <option value="Pass" ${screen.screenResult == 'Pass' ? 'selected' : ''}>Pass</option>
                                <option value="Fail" ${screen.screenResult == 'Fail' ? 'selected' : ''}>Fail</option>
                                <option value="" ${screen.screenResult == '' ? 'selected' : ''}></option>
                            </select>   
                       </td>
                   </tr>
                    <tr><td>&nbsp</td><td> &nbsp</td></tr>


                </c:forEach>
            </table>

            <input type="submit" class="saveButton" value="SAVE">
        </form>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do that but to adhere to the MVC design, probably it would be best to spend some time to learn about the [ActionForm](http://struts.apache.org/1.3.10/userGuide/building_controller.html). That way, you can do validation to your form in a java class that extends ActionForm. In class ConfirmEditApplicantAction, you can code the business logic here which is more systematic.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why it shouldn't be OK. Have you actually run that code to see if it works? If it does, then I don't see any problem with it and it should be OK. And if it doesn't, well, then it most likely is not OK since you have no working code.

Comment: Pardon me for the vague question but what I meant here was that if it does not violate any coding rules or standards when I convert the servlet codes into struts. Because I know that the ActionForm class is used when passing the values from the jsp to the Action class.

Comment: @mr. yoso OK, I see. Well, in that case I'd still say that if it works, you can do it that way. If you have the time and the energy, then by all means make it more Struts-like with ActionForms. But if this is work-related then there probably are time and budget constraints to what you can do.

Answer (score 0):

The struts way to deal with request parameters is to put a property of the same name as the parameter in the ActionForm, and let Struts populate it for you. This way, you don't have to deal with request parameters at all, but rather, are dealing with ActionForm properties.
So, to answer your question, instead of coding
code:`<%= request.getParameter("name") %>`

I would code a the property "name" in my ActionForm with a getName() and a setName() method.
In my jsp, I would then code:
code:`<bean:write name="MyForm" property="name"/>`

OR.. `<bean parameter id="username" name="user"/> and <%=username%>`
If the jsp is called with a name parameter, struts will automatically populate the form bean with the name property.

This is why there's no struts tag that I know of to display a request parameter.
There is one in jstl, however:`<c:out value="${param.name}" />`